# How do I implement Dijkstra's parallel all source shortest path algorithm with MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, dijkstra

I am working on a presentation to compare two parallel formulation of Dijkstra's all source shortest path algorithm. 
I have referred a few codes online but they don't work with MPI library.
How do I implement this?